# web2py - Create Dropdown field from table but also add new record to table

Tags: drop-down-menu, addition, web2py

I very new to web2py and some more experience is needed for my app.
My task is "simple one".

I want to create an app where the user can insert to a table with 3 Field. My tables field_1 is the same for some values of field2 and field3. 
First solution was to define_table in field properties to use IS_IN_SET but field_1 values cant be known from the start of the project.
Second solution was to create the form using SQLFORM.factory but in this case if a new value in field_1 is required, user cant added it and a new controller def must be added.

My first through was to create a new add_field1 table with a submision form and connecting to my first table.

But is there any properties in .factory that give user a dropdown menu for a field but also to insert a new record to the field in the same form?

Ty

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but it seems to me that you want to have a form for users to add values to a database which has a drop down menu that is filled with your database's values.

If that is the case then you can do it by having this be your sqlform statement:

```
my_form = SQLFORM(db.my_table)
```

Then you can just define my_table as:

```
define_table('my_table',
    Field('field1', 'reference other_table', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, db.other_table, '%(field_name)s'),
)
```

This will create a table that when created with sqlform will give a form with a drop down list of values from the column 'field_name' in the table other_table.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can have a dropdown of fields without knowing what the fields are to begin with...

How about using the reference  definition for field in web2py. But it automatically assumes that you have all your choices in the database. So then you would just have two forms on the same page, one to add the choices and the other to pick a choice.

An example would be to have a field in table myLine with colors defined in another table color:

```
db.define_table('colors',
    Field('name','string'),
    Field('code','string'),
    format='%(name)s')
if db(db.colors).isempty():
    # create instance of table
    for k,v in dict(red="#FF0000",black="#000000",blue="#0000FF").items():
        db.color.insert(name=k,code=v)

db.define_table('myLine',
    Field('name','string'),
    Field('color','reference colors'))
```